# Why does my command stop when I exit SSH?

Tags: centos, ssh, centos6, nohup

I am running the following command in a loop (without notable memory leaks) as a cPanel user:

```
nohup php ~/www/app/console.php run clean 1> /dev/null 2> ~/www/logs/run_clean.log &
```

But when I exit SSH, the command always stops. When I do a `htop` as root, I can't see the process running.

If I don't exit the SSH for days, for instance, the process will continue running fine!

What is wrong? Is not expected for the command I have posted to run in the background without interruption?

Comment: Just put it into a `screen` or `tmux` session. It's reliable and easier than to fiddle with `nohup` and I/O redirection.

Comment: @SvW What if I need another `screen` session? The previous one will not be closed?

Comment: No, it will not be closed. You can have multiple screen sessions with multiple windows open for each.  Read about how `screen` works. It's a godsend and about the most useful tool for remote work next to `ssh`.

Comment: @SvW Worked fine! (:

Answer (score 2):

The command might detect its stdin being closed at logout. Try redirecting it from `/dev/null`:

```
nohup php ~/www/app/console.php run clean 1> /dev/null 2> ~/www/logs/run_clean.log  </dev/null &
```

Comment: It says "exit", when I `exit`, without command stdin.

Comment: I can see the proccess when `htop` only before `exit`, but no after.